# How to get list of device recently used and currently on bluetooth as well as in background in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I tried but i didn't get any device list near by me.
below code i tried.I apperciate your answer and please help me.Thank you in advance.

```
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == .poweredOn {
            let option:[String:Any] = [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:true]
            self.manager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: option)
        }
        else {
            print("Bluetooth is not available")
        }
    }
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        print("peripheral:=\(peripheral.name)")
        if let device = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey] as? String {

           print("peripheral_ UUID:=\(peripheral.services)")
            if let service = peripheral.services {
                BEAN_SERVICE_UUID = service[0].uuid
                let idstr = service[0].characteristics![0].uuid
                BEAN_SCRATCH_UUID = idstr
                print("BEAN_SERVICE_UUID:=\(BEAN_SERVICE_UUID)")
            }

            manager.stopScan()
            self.peripheral = peripheral
            self.peripheral.delegate = self

            manager.connect(self.peripheral, options: nil)
        }
        else {
            print("device not Found")
        }
    }
```

Comment: "devices Recently used": Not possible. And are the devices you are looking for even Bluetooth Low Energy?

Comment: So What i need to do, can you help me now?

Comment: And that doesn't answer my question: " And are the devices you are looking for even Bluetooth Low Energy?" and as I said, you can't find the devices recently used, Apple doesn't allow it.